# How to have the "close", "maximize" and "minimize" buttons on the left in google-chrome in kde

Tags: configuration, kde, google-chrome, window-buttons

I would like to achieve what I was able to do in Ubuntu.

I've now switched to KDE and would like to have the buttons on the left hand side.

I have already set it for the "native" windows and they look like this:

[image]

I would like to have this:

[image]

On the other side (left).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Start google-chorme like this:

```
$ DESKTOP_SESSION="gnome" google-chrome
```

Just one "little" caveat: when it starts, it doesn't know it *IS* the default browser.

Comment: I'm using XFCE and chromium and this worked (substituting `chromium-browser` for `google-chrome`)

Answer (score 1):

```
System Settings -> Workspace Apperance ->  Windows Decorations -> Configure Buttons
```

- from there, check "Use custom titlebar button positions".  Below that, you can drag around windows title bar items in whatever orientation you refer, as well as add/remove items.[image]

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, I have already done that, see the first screen shot. I was talking specifically about chrome that apparently handles things differently.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use gnome-settings-daemon to trick Chrome into using metacity's layout (if you still have gnome installed that is).

If you have metacity installed and set to have the buttons on the left, add gnome-settings-daemon to your kde startup applications. You will need to relog for things to take effect. If my hunch is correct, Chrome will read the settings it believes GNOME has, and put the buttons on the left side.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm doing things correctly, I have tried adding the command you provided in the Autostart app in KDE and but it doesnt seem to accept it as a command. Is it in Autostart I need to add it? is it in any special conditions? run a program or run a script? Thanks!

Comment: Try /usr/bin/gnome-settings-daemon - it *should* work (I think it's a command).

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to be working. I hope I'm not doing anything wrong but I tried as many combinations as I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

Trufa I use Ubuntu Tweak to make those kind of adjustments. http://ubuntu-tweak.com/ you can change a lot of different things with Ubuntu Tweak. I hope this helps!

Comment: Last time i used it on KDE it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` like in this answer: 
[How to change gtk button-layout in KDE?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412195)

In Chrome Settings enable: `Use system title bar and borders`